# How can I use GitPrefix extension in VS Code to only show JIRA ID?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I recently installed the GitPrefix extension for VS Code and it's great. However, in the commit message, I'd like to add only the JIRA ID of the branch, and not the full branch name. Example:

- Branch name: `JIRA-1234-this-is-a-branch` = Commit message prefix: `JIRA-1234`
- Branch name: `WEB3-4321-this-is-a-branch` = Commit message prefix: `WEB3-4321`

In the attached image, what regex should I add and to which setting should it be added to?

[Git Prefix settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkS2F.png)

I've tried adding this, `((?<!([A-Za-z]{1,10})-?)[A-Z]+-\d+)`, and other variations, but either it does not match the branch name or the whole branch name is prefixed in the commit message.

Comment: Please don't add a "solved" marker and don't put your solution in the question. stackoverflow has a fairly strict separation of question and answers; see the [tour]. You can answer your own question, though, so just move your solution to an answer. (You can even accept the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [Boodain](/users/22299962)'s question post.

> After installing the extension, clicking the GitPrefix commit message button inputs the whole branch name. If you want to only add the JIRA ID of the branch name, do the following:
>
> 1. In VS Code, at the bottom left, click the settions gear icon and then click Settings.
> 2. In the settings search bar, search for “gitprefix”.
> 3. Under Git Prefix: Pattern, change the regular expressions to `^([A-Z,0-9]+-\d+).*.`
>
> Now, when you click the GitPrefix commit button, only the JIRA ID is filled into the commit message.